# Convert Python 1D List to tuple pair

Tags: python, list, tuples

I **have** a list of integers:

`[0, 6, 43, 10, 48, 1]`

and I **want** to convert it to tuple pairs like this:

`[(0, 6), (6,43), (43,10), (10,48), (48,1)]`

I tried this solution `zip(shortest_path[::2], shortest_path[1::2])` however doesn't overlap the elements. For example, in the tuple example above, each element is repeated twice except the first and last.

Thanks

Comment: `for tpl in zip(L, L[1:]):` works.

Comment: ...or `list(zip(L, L[1:]))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `zip` and slice notation:

```
data = [0, 6, 43, 10, 48, 1]
output = list(zip(data, data[1:]))
```

---

```
[(0, 6), (6, 43), (43, 10), (10, 48), (48, 1)]
```